# How to get a list of the elements in TreeView? PyGtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a treeview, with some elements in it.
How can I get a list of all this data?
Is there something similar to this,

```
self.treeview.GetItems()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you get the model:

```
model = self.treeview.get_model()
```

And then you have tons of different ways to access your data/items depending on what you want and how the model look... For more on that check [http://pygtk.org](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodel.html)

You could get first row by doing:

```
model[0]
```

And also you could iterate through it...